# UIDatePicker with "done" button

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, button, datepicker

I need to add a "done" button to my date picker like in this image:

[image]

This is my code:

```
-(IBAction)chooseDate:(id)sender{
self.datepicker= [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 216)];
    self.datepicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    datepicker.backgroundColor = Rgb2UIColor(52, 170, 220);

    [self.btnDone
                addTarget:self
                action:@selector(SetDatePickerTime:)
                forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

 [self.view addSubview:self.datepicker];
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do?  What is your problem?

Comment: I need to do this http://mjstelly.files.wordpress.com/2011/08/datepicker.png?w=230&h=300

Comment: create a UIView and add it to the main view. Add a UIDatePicker to the new UIView. Add two UIButtons to the UIView.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a date picker, then add it as the input view of the field in question (`self.fieldInQuestion.inputView = datePicker`). Next, create a `UIToolBar` (height 44) with `UIBarButton` Item on it with the title "Done", target of self, and a selector (ex. @selector(done)). Add this as the input accessory view of the same field you made the date picker an input view for (`self.fieldInQuestion.inputAccessoryView = UIToolbarInstance`). In the selector method (-(void)done in the example above), make sure you use [self.fieldInQuestion resignFirstResponder] and it will dismiss it.

Comment: i get inputAccessoryView is a read-only property when trying to assign my uitoolbar to it

Comment: @user1709076 Use `[fieldInQuestion setInputAccessoryView: toolbar]`

Answer (score 22):

With Swift

```
// Place this code inside your ViewController or where you want ;)

var txtField: UITextField = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 50))

// the formatter should be "compliant" to the UIDatePickerMode selected below
var dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter {
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    // customize the locale for the formatter if you want
    //formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "it_IT")
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    return formatter
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // date picker setup
    let datePickerView:UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()

    // choose the mode you want
    // other options are: DateAndTime, Time, CountDownTimer
    datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date

    // choose your locale or leave the default (system)
    //datePickerView.locale = NSLocale.init(localeIdentifier: "it_IT")

    datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: "onDatePickerValueChanged:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    txtField.inputView = datePickerView

    // datepicker toolbar setup
    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
    toolBar.translucent = true
    let space = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: self, action: "doneDatePickerPressed")

    // if you remove the space element, the "done" button will be left aligned
    // you can add more items if you want
    toolBar.setItems([space, doneButton], animated: false)
    toolBar.userInteractionEnabled = true
    toolBar.sizeToFit()

    txtField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

    self.view.addSubview(txtField)
}

func doneDatePickerPressed(){
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

func onDatePickerValueChanged(datePicker: UIDatePicker) {
    self.txtField = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(datePicker.date)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The reference image of your question is showing that the app is using UIToolbar and i will assume that when tapping on date text field the datepicker with done button appears.And for this in 
some.h file

```
/*****keyboard Done button   ***/



#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
   IBOutlet UIDatePicker *picker1;
    IBOutlet UITextField *txtFld;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIToolbar *keyboardToolbar;

@end
```

in some.m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
 picker1=[[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 300)];//frames are just for demo
 [txtFld setInputView:picker1];
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if(keyboardToolbar == nil) {
        keyboardToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 410, 320, 44)] ;
        [keyboardToolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
        [keyboardToolbar sizeToFit];

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4];

        UIBarButtonItem *flexButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];

        UIBarButtonItem *doneButton1 =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(resignKeyboard)];
        NSArray *itemsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexButton,doneButton1, nil];

        [keyboardToolbar setItems:itemsArray];


        [txtFld setInputAccessoryView:keyboardToolbar];
        [self.view addSubview:keyboardToolbar];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}



-(void)resignKeyboard {

    [keyboardToolbar removeFromSuperview];
    [txtFld resignFirstResponder];
///do nescessary date calculation here

    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In Swift 5

```
//Create this variable
var picker:UIDatePicker?

//Write Date picker code
picker = UIDatePicker()
dobTF.inputView = picker//Change your textfield name
picker?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleDatePicker), for: .valueChanged)
picker?.datePickerMode = .date

//Write toolbar code for done button
let toolBar = UIToolbar()
toolBar.barStyle = .default
toolBar.isTranslucent = true
let space = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(onClickDoneButton))
toolBar.setItems([space, doneButton], animated: false)
toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
toolBar.sizeToFit()
dobTF.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

//Date picker function
@objc func handleDatePicker() {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy" //Change your date formate
    let strDate = dateFormatter.string(from: picker!.date)
    dobTF.text = strDate
}

//Toolbar done button function
@objc func onClickDoneButton() {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**I DO!!!!**

```
-(IBAction)ChooseDate:(id)sender{

btnDone = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

[done setTitle:@"GO!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btnDone.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x1F1F21);
btnDone.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[btnDone addTarget:self
           action:@selector(HidePicker:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:btnDone];


    self.datepicker= [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 216)];
    self.datepicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    datepicker.backgroundColor = Rgb2UIColor(52, 170, 220);
    
    [self.view addSubview:self.datepicker];
}


-(IBAction)HidePicker:(id)sender{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^{
                         datepicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, -250, 320, 50);
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [datepicker removeFromSuperview];
                         [btnDone removeFromSuperview];
                     }];

    [self.datepicker removeFromSuperview];
    NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"ddMMyyyy"];
   
    //NSLOG
    NSLog(@"%@",[outputFormatter stringFromDate:self.datepicker.date]);
}
```