# Add a Done button within a pop-up datePickerView in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield, uidatepicker

I want to add a Done button within a popped up datePickerView in Swift.

Here is the code:

```
@IBOutlet var datePicker: UITextField!

@IBAction func dateTextInputPressed(sender: UITextField) {

    var datePickerView = UIDatePicker()
    datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date

    sender.inputView = datePickerView
    datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: Selector("handleDatePicker:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
}

func handleDatePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    datePicker.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
}
```

I can use this code to pop up a datePickerView successfully.

[image: result of datePickerView]

But after I've selected the date, it does not have a "Done" button to dismiss it.

So how can I add the Done button into it?

Comment: in Swift 5 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27050988/uidatepicker-with-done-button/58023152#58023152

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I made this extension to close the picker. **Swift 2**

```
extension UIToolbar {

 func ToolbarPiker(mySelect : Selector) -> UIToolbar {

    let toolBar = UIToolbar()

    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
    toolBar.translucent = true
    toolBar.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    toolBar.sizeToFit()

    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: mySelect)
    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)

    toolBar.setItems([ spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
    toolBar.userInteractionEnabled = true

    return toolBar
}

}
```

**Swift 3 - 4**

```
extension UIToolbar {

func ToolbarPiker(mySelect : Selector) -> UIToolbar {

    let toolBar = UIToolbar()

    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
    toolBar.isTranslucent = true
    toolBar.tintColor = UIColor.black
    toolBar.sizeToFit()

    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: mySelect)
    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)

    toolBar.setItems([ spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
    toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    return toolBar
}

}
```

And you can use it simply in your viewController:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

 //SWIFT2
 /*
let toolBar = UIToolbar().ToolbarPiker(#selector(MyViewController.dismissPicker))

 */
// Swift3 - 4
    let toolBar = UIToolbar().ToolbarPiker(mySelect: #selector(MyViewController.dismissPicker))

    myTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar


}

 // Swift 2 - 3
 func dismissPicker() { 

    view.endEditing(true)

}

 // Swift 4
 @objc func dismissPicker() { 

    view.endEditing(true)

}
```

Comment: Excellent solution. One small correction about the swift 3 code: let toolBar = UIToolbar().ToolbarPiker(mySelect: #selector

Comment: @JUL2791 after the before code myTextField.inputView = myPikerView  where you want, for example inside  Editing Did Begin function of UITextField (myTextField)

Comment: I want to display picker on tap of button and selecting after selecting from Picker assign it to button title. So inputAccessoryView won't work for UIButton. Any other solution?

Answer (score 15):

You can use a generic `UIView` for the `inputView` property of the `UITextField`. We can add the `UIDatePicker` and `UIButton` to this `UIView`.

```
@IBAction func dateTextInputPressed(sender: UITextField) {

    //Create the view
    let inputView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, 240))


    var datePickerView  : UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker(frame: CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0))
    datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
    inputView.addSubview(datePickerView) // add date picker to UIView

    let doneButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width/2) - (100/2), 0, 100, 50))
    doneButton.setTitle("Done", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    doneButton.setTitle("Done", forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)
    doneButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    doneButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.grayColor(), forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)

    inputView.addSubview(doneButton) // add Button to UIView

    doneButton.addTarget(self, action: "doneButton:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside) // set button click event

    sender.inputView = inputView
    datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: Selector("handleDatePicker:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

    handleDatePicker(datePickerView) // Set the date on start.
}

func handleDatePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    datePicker.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
}

func doneButton(sender:UIButton)
{
    datePicker.resignFirstResponder() // To resign the inputView on clicking done.
}
```

Answer (score 6):

if you are using a button instead of text field:

/**
    * MARK - Advance booking action
    */

```
@IBAction func advanceBookingAction(sender: UIButton) {

    var datePicker : UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
    var datePickerContainer = UIView()

    datePickerContainer.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, self.view.frame.height/2, 320.0, 300.0)
    datePickerContainer.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    var pickerSize : CGSize = datePicker.sizeThatFits(CGSizeZero)
    datePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 20, pickerSize.width, 460)
    datePicker.setDate(NSDate(), animated: true)
    datePicker.maximumDate = NSDate()
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.DateAndTime
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: "dateChangedInDate:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    datePickerContainer.addSubview(datePicker)

    var doneButton = UIButton()
    doneButton.setTitle("Done", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    doneButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    doneButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("dismissPicker:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    doneButton.frame    = CGRectMake(250.0, 5.0, 70.0, 37.0)

    datePickerContainer.addSubview(doneButton)

    self.view.addSubview(datePickerContainer)

}// end advanceBookingAction

/**
* MARK - observer to get the change in date
*/

func dateChangedInDate(sender:UIDatePicker){

    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.LongStyle
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle
    objMethodInc.printvj("date selected \(datePicker.date)")

}// end dateChangedInDate

/*
* MARK - dismiss the date picker value
*/
func dismissPicker(sender: UIButton) {
    objMethodInc.printvj("dismiss date picker")
    datePickerContainer.removeFromSuperview()
}// end dismissPicker
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 5

If you want only **Done** button on DatePicker use my code

```
//Write toolbar code for done button
let toolBar = UIToolbar()
toolBar.barStyle = .default
toolBar.isTranslucent = true
let space = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(onClickDoneButton))
toolBar.setItems([space, doneButton], animated: false)
toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
toolBar.sizeToFit()
dobTF.inputAccessoryView = toolBar //Change your TextField name here

@objc func onClickDoneButton() {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@IBOutlet weak var txtDate: UITextField!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    //Write toolbar code for done button
    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.barStyle = .default
    toolBar.isTranslucent = true
    let space = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(onClickDoneButton))
    toolBar.setItems([space, doneButton], animated: false)
    toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    toolBar.sizeToFit()
    txtDate.inputAccessoryView = toolBar //Change your TextField name here
    
    let datePickerView = UIDatePicker()
    datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePicker.Mode.date
    
    txtDate.inputView = datePickerView
    datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleDatePicker(sender:)), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
    
}

@objc func onClickDoneButton() {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

@objc func handleDatePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    txtDate.text = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
}
```

Comment: Combined above answers for Swift 5