# Swift - Custom inputView for text field with IB?

Tags: ios, swift, xib, inputview, uiinputviewcontroller

I've been trying to figure this out all day and I feel completely lost.

I have a text field that I'd like to be able to edit using a customized inputView. (For example, a custom inputView that contains a `UIDatePicker` with a "done" button to dismiss it, and maybe a couple of other buttons as well.) I'd like to design this inputView in interface builder (in a storyboard or xib), and set it as the text field's inputView.

I cannot figure out what I'm supposed to do to connect everything up. I don't understand how to take buttons in my xib for the custom inputView and wire them up to actions in my main view controller.

I saw a similar question answered here: [Add a Done button within a pop-up datePickerView in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28048469/how-to-add-a-done-button-within-a-poped-up-datepickerview-in-swift) 
but here, the "done" button is constructed programmatically.

Can somebody help me find the most straightforward way to do what I'm trying to do?

Apologies if my question is confusing --- I'm pretty lost right now.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Add datepicker and toolbar on xib. Check the screenshot.

[image]

Step 2: Create the outlets for both of DatePicker and textfield.

Step 3: Write the following lines in viewDidLoad

```
txtField.inputView = datePicker
txtField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
```

Screenshot of my code.

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, I completely am not understanding what you've done here. Could you explain the process in more detail?