# How to add UIDatePicker into UIAlertController iOS9

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker, uialertcontroller

I try to add date piker into `alertcontroller` but have some problems with size. I don't know how to get height of `datepiker` or just `init` `UIAlertController` with height of date piker. 
So what i did:

```
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:@"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

UIView *viewDatePicker = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 200)];
[viewDatePicker setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 200);
UIDatePicker *picker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
[picker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeTime];

[viewDatePicker addSubview:picker];

[alertController.view addSubview:viewDatePicker];

NSDateFormatter *formate=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formate setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a "];
UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                      handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {

                                                          sinceDateString = [formate stringFromDate:picker.date];
                                                          [sinceDateButton setTitle:sinceDateString forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                                                      }];

[alertController addAction:defaultAction];
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

> I find this solution one of the same question  UIAlertController
>   *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:@"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
>   preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

But i know that it's wrong solution because i see gray lines.
[image: UIAlertController]

Comment: that is selection line of your current date selected ,

Comment: Oh, sorry Iam new in iOS dev. but what about "\n\n\n" there is only one solution add height of UIAlertController?

Comment: \n means create new line

Comment: ok does not a problem , search in google more you get the easiest answer in always, do well

Answer (score 3):

why you are not choosed the `UIDatePicker` for your concept, see this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27050988/uidatepicker-with-done-button)

> \n is the new line character ,it moves the position to starting of next line

and your second question in center it shows the *gray line*, it means you r datepicker selection area of date.

> in your code you used the **\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n** in 10 times, remove two 
>   \n\n then shows perfect.

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:@"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

UIView *viewDatePicker = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,200)];
[viewDatePicker setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 200);
UIDatePicker *picker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
[picker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeTime];

[viewDatePicker addSubview:picker];

[alertController.view addSubview:viewDatePicker];

NSDateFormatter *formate=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formate setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                      handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {

                                                          //                                                              sinceDateString = [formate stringFromDate:picker.date];
                                                          //                                                              [sinceDateButton setTitle:sinceDateString forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                                                      }];

[alertController addAction:defaultAction];
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and i  got the output like

[image]

Comment: check the update answer, but in here my suggestion use `UIDatePicker`

Comment: Thanks you it was helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Adding UIDatePicker to action sheet was discouraged by Apple all along. Since iOS 7, Apple had introduced the use of inline date picker (see how it is done in the Calendar app).

If you managed to hack a workaround using UIAlertController, it may probably break again in future iOS releases.